# Laravel belongsToMany get one record

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables as below:

**users**
id|name|username|password

**roles**
id|name

**users_roles**
id|user_id|role_id

These tables communicate via belongsToMany.
Table users_roles has many records. The user can change his role, but I have to store every change.

| id | user_id | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

1st. How can I get the last and single role_id with the user?

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
```

Now I'm getting user(2) with two roles, but I need user(2) with single and last role(3).

2nd. How I can access roles->name on the blade?

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }} <<< normal
    {{ $user->roles['name']}}  <<I'm getting error here
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel version is 8.40

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`roles` will be a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#introduction) so you could just use the [last()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-last) method and have something like:

```
$user->roles->last()->name;
```

---

Alternatively, if you can update to Laravel >= 8.42, you could use the [Has one of many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many).

Create a new relationship in your `User` model:

```
public function latestRole()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

Then you would load the role with `latestRole`:

```
$users = User::with('latestRole')->get();
```

This way you can access the relationship directly:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->latestRole->name }}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but `latestOfMany` only works for 1:N and not for N:N relationships. Otherwise you will get `Unknown column 'users.role_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: @Luciano Yes, I believe you're right. I could be wrong (and it would probably depend on your specific circumstance) but if you have a model set up for your pivot table you may be able to use [hasOneThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through).

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereHas

```
 $users = User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
        $q->latest();
    })->get();
```